Execute stored procedure created in Serverless SQL pool through the Stored procedure activity in ADF?
Can we execute the stored procedure that we have created in Serverless SQL pool through the Stored procedure activity in ADF?
I am attempting to construct a pipeline to run my stored procedure, but I am unable to locate the stored procedure within Workspace > SQL database. Despite refreshing, it still doesn't appear.

As you mentioned that you are unable to locate the stored procedure within Workspace.
You can try and query in Synapse Studio:
SELECT definition, uses_ansi_nulls, uses_quoted_identifier, is_schema_bound  
FROM sys.sql_modules  
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test');   
GO 

Results:
definition  uses_ansi_nulls uses_quoted_identifier  is_schema_bound
"Create proc Test
as
Select 1 as X"  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE

To use the Stored procedure created in the serverless pool within pipeline you follow the below steps:
Create a linked service for your serverless pool.
You can get the fully qualified domain name for the serverless pool from the synapse workspace overview


Next, use a stored procedure activity under genral tab.

